# How do I set global Gradle properties in an init script?

Tags: gradle

I would like to move company-specific configuration out of my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and into an init script, `~/.gradle/company.init.gradle`.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to defien global Gradle properties in a init script in the same way that I would do so in a `gradle.properties` file.

My `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` currently has:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.caching=true
com.company.artifactory.username=drew.stephens@company.com
com.company.artifactory.apiKey=<api_key>
com.company.artifactory.contextUrl=https://company.jfrog.io/company
```

And I would like to move those Artifactory values to a company-specific init script, `~/.gradle/company.init.gradle` (mainly because I commit my `gradle.properties` to my [home directory repo](https://github.com/dinomite/homedir/blob/master/.gradle/gradle.properties)):

```
gradle.allprojects {
    com.company.artifactory.username=drew.stephens@company.com
    com.company.artifactory.apiKey=<api_key>
    com.company.artifactory.contextUrl=https://company.jfrog.io/company
}
```

But neither of those methods makes the property accessible from my buildscript:

```
task('foobar') {
    // Outputs "null"
    println(project.properties['com.company.artifactory.username'])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of [Gradle 5.5](https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/release-notes.html#define-organization-wide-properties-with-a-custom-gradle-distribution), you can place `gradle.properties` in a [custom Gradle distribution](https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:custom_gradle_distribution).

I'm not aware of a way to set these properties in an init script.

Comment: Thanks—that will work for folks who need to do what I originally asked, but what I actually want to store are user-specific properties (username & password for the Artifactory server).  I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way you can also use environment variables to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

According to [gradle.allprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:allprojects(org.gradle.api.Action)) your configuration action occurs against all *currently available and evaluated* projects, and later after new projects have been evaluated. According to how I understand what you want to achieve, I believe that [gradle.beforeProject](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:beforeProject(org.gradle.api.Action)) would be the place to add your properties.